# 40GB .SQL File in MySQL to SQL Database on Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a 40GB .sql file on my computer that I downloaded from an external AWS source. It is designed for MySQL. Using an advanced text editor, I'm able to view the file but I fear that I can't break it up into smaller pieces reliably. Is there a tool or process for migrating it to SQL Database on Azure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. Create ClearDB MySQL instance
2. Import data from your 40GB .sql file there
3. Create Azure SQL Database
4. Use [MySQLToSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/migrating-mysql-data-into-sql-server-azure-sql-db-mysqltosql) to re-import MySQL to Azure SQL

Another option would be to use directly [Azure Database for MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/), but that is still in preview. It depends if you want to stick with MySQL or transition really to "Microsoft's SQL".